# Trouble with if statemtent and drop down list

Tags: php

I am modifying an online shop where a product has several size options to choose from. customers use a drop-down list which is populated with the sizes to choose what size he/she wants. I am trying to modify it so that when the stock for a certain size runs out ($in_stock becomes 0), the option in the drop-down list for that particular size gets the text '- Out' added to it. So far this is what I have, and the problem I am having is when the condition if($in_stock == 0) is satisfied, the text '- Out' is being put on every single sizes in the drop down list, rather than just the size that has run out. Could anyone point out what I am doing wrong with the code?

Plus, how do I make the size option that ran out of stock become greyed out and be unselectable?

If any part of the code doesn't make sense please ask (I'm using an eCommerce platform called Lemonstand. Here is its API http://v1.lemonstand.com/api/).

Thanks

```
  <label class="title" for="<?= $control_name ?>"><?= h($option->name) ?></label>
    <select name="<?= $control_name ?>" onchange="return $(this).getForm().sendRequest('on_action', {onAfterUpdate: init_effects, update: {'product-page': 'shop:product'}})">
      <?
      $values = $option->list_values();
      foreach ($values as $value){
        if($in_stock == 0):

            $value = $value."- Out";
        }
      ?>

      <option <?= option_state($posted_value, $value) ?> value="<?= h($value) ?>"><?= h($value) ?></option>
      <? endforeach ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: where do you wanna end your if and I think your foreach is already ended??

Comment: How do you set the `$in_stock` variable? It seems to me that your `$in_stock` variable should be changing in your for loop, since each size should have it's own value for `$in_stock`.  Since, `$in_stock` doesn't change in your for loop, when whichever size `$in_stock` refers to goes to 0 the line `if($in_stock == 0)` will be true for every size.

Comment: I get $in_stock (number of stocks remaining) from $in_stock = $product->om('in_stock', $posted_options);. The code is saying get whatever number is under the in_stock column in the table that stores the product information. $product is an object that contains info about the product name, size, stocks left for that size....etc. I'm not sure what $posted_option is, I copied it from the Lemonstand API: here:https://v1.lemonstand.com/api/class/shop_product/#om()

Comment: I would paste the whole code here but I have to wait for another 8 hours before I could do that (Stackoverflow site rule) :)

Comment: I see your point elitechief21. How would you change the code to make it go through the $product object and get $in_stock for each size rather than just getting the same value for all sizes?

Answer (score 0):

I get $in_stock (number of stocks remaining) from $in_stock = $product->om('in_stock', $posted_options);. The code is saying get whatever number is under the in_stock column in the table that stores the product information. $product is an object that contains info about the product name, size, stocks left for that size....etc. I'm not sure what $posted_option is, I copied it from the Lemonstand API: here:https://v1.lemonstand.com/api/class/shop_product/#om()

```
<? if ($product->options->count):
```

foreach ($product->options as $option):
      $control_name = 'product_options['.$option->option_key.']';

```
  $posted_options = Shop_ProductHelper::get_default_options($product);

  //gets current stock
  $in_stock = $product->om('in_stock', $posted_options);

  $posted_value = isset($posted_options[$option->option_key]) ? $posted_options[$option->option_key] : null;
?>
  <label class="title" for="<?= $control_name ?>"><?= h($option->name) ?></label>
    <select name="<?= $control_name ?>" onchange="return $(this).getForm().sendRequest('on_action', {onAfterUpdate: init_effects, update: {'product-page': 'shop:product'}})">
      <?
      $values = $option->list_values();
                var_dump($values);

      foreach ($values as $value):
        if($in_stock ==119):

            $value = $value."- Out";
        endif
      ?>

      <option <?= option_state($posted_value, $value) ?> value="<?= h($value) ?>"><?= h($value) ?></option>
      <? endforeach ?>
    </select>
<? endforeach ?>
```